# How to enable mod_rewrite for virtual host

Tags: 12.04, apache2, virtualhost

The mod_rewrite rule is not working on the virtual host. 
I have wanted this for cakephp.

Is there setting to add in the virtual host file?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you are using latest apache version 2.4+ then here is the process how to enable mod_rewrite.
Go to `etc/apache2/`
Open `apache2.conf` using your favorite text editor.
Change

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

to

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Then save it. Remember you should have root permission to edit and save this file.
Now restart apache.

```
service apache2 reload
```

This process will enable mod_rewrite for apache server including virtual host.

You can also check if it's enabled or not. Create a php script

```
<?php    
phpinfo();    
?>
```

Load it from server. Under `Loaded Modules` section check if `mod_rewrite` is there or not. If it's there then it is enabled.

Comment: Before I use this option all my rewrites were ending up at 404, however after updating `apache2.conf` and restarting `apache` 404 disappeared but all pages landed back on homepage! `phpinfo()` did not have  `mod_rewrite` module enabled either. Then running CLI commnd (as suggested by Lonston below) everything gone golden! Why this solution did not enable `mod-rewrite` module for me but the CLI approad? Is this a combination of modifying `.conf` and running CLI command one after another to enable the module or either of these is actually enough?

Answer (score 6):

**Enable Rewrite using**

```
# sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Then restart the apcahe2 using

```
# service apache2 restart
```

Enable in Virtualhost by adding

```
AllowOverride FileInfo
```

Then restart the apcahe2 using

```
# service apache2 restart
```

**example**:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            # I Have below line from none to FileInfo
            AllowOverride FileInfo
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
```

Comment: This worked for me too!