# How to complete my URL header in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a website `www.example.com` running on Apache.

Maybe someone got to me via `example.com`, or `www.example.com`, or `http://example.com`, or even `http://www.example.com`.

Can I use the rewrite rules in `.htaccess` so that however they get to `example.com`, the URL is fully fleshed out to `http://www.example.com`?

Comment: What about HTTPS? Do you have a security certificate installed?

Comment: @MrWhite I do not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming Apache is already accepting requests to both the www subdomain and the domain apex (ie. `example.com`) then you can canonicalize the hostname to www using something like the following using mod_rewrite near the top of your `.htaccess` file in the document root.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

The above redirects any request of the form `example.com/<anything>` to `http://www.example.com/<anything>`. The `REQUEST_URI` server variable contains the full URL-path, including the slash prefix. Any query string that might be on the original request is passed through unchanged.

Test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid potential caching issues.

> Maybe someone got to me via `example.com`, or `www.example.com`, or `http://example.com`, or even `http://www.example.com`.

NB: `example.com` and `http://example.com` are the same - the browser simply hides the protocol (and defaults to HTTP for *most* users). The same for `www.example.com` and `http://www.example.com`.

---

**UPDATE:**

> when I just tried this out, the browser URL remains `example.com`

If you haven't done so already, you need to enable `.htaccess` overrides in the server config, otherwise the `.htaccess` file will simply be ignored.

In the appropriate `<Directory>` container inside the `<VirtualHost>` (or main server config) you need to set `AllowOverride` (the default is `None). For example:

```
<Directory /path/to/document-root>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    Require all granted

    # Enable .htaccess overrides
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

AND, if you haven't already, you need to enable mod_rewrite:

- [How to enable mod_rewrite for virtual host](https://askubuntu.com/questions/423514/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-virtual-host)

#### Debugging `.htaccess`

You can increase the `LogLevel` (Apache 2.4+) in the server config to output debug information to the server's error log. For example, in the respective  `<VirtualHost>` container (or main server config):

```
LogLevel debug
```

This sets the "log level" for all modules. The default is `LogLevel warn`. To target just a specific module, such as mod_rewrite (used above) then you can specify just that module. eg. `LogLevel rewrite:debug`.

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#loglevel
- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html#permodule

Comment: There are subdirectories, obviously, on my website. Will this include them? Also, does .htaccess have a print feature? So I can debug? Because when I just tried this out, the browser URL remains example.com.

Comment: @DanielKaplan Yes, as mentioned, this redirects `example.com/<anything>`, copying the URL-path (ie. `<anything>`) onto the target URL. You need to enable `.htaccess` overrides in the server config if you haven't already. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I've added more info about "debugging". There is no "print feature" as such.

Comment: Rewrite is on, but to test I changed one of your lines to this: 'RewriteRule ^ http://ww4w.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]' figuring it should fail.  it does not.

Comment: (_Aside:_ To format inline code in comments use _backticks_.) @DanielKaplan

Comment: @DanielKaplan Try typing some _nonesense_ at the top of the `.htaccess` file. Do you get an error? If no error then `.htaccess` overrides are not enabled and you need to set `AllowOverride All` at the appropriate place in the server config (as mentioned above). Apache needs to be restarted after making changes to the server config.

Comment: no error reported with garbage at top. I have 'RewriteEngine on' at top of .htaccess (although I have more than one htacess file, this one is at the root (public_html). As well, in sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf I have <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        AllowOverride All
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

Comment: As well when I enter the command 'sudo a2enmod rewrite' it tells me that Module rewrite already enabled

Comment: @DanielKaplan Do you have a symlink from `sites-enabled` to `sites-available`? You say "this one is at the root (public_html)", but you have `DocumentRoot /var/www/html`? Where does `public_html` fit into this? `AllowOverride All` needs to be defined inside a `<Directory>` container (as shown above), not directly inside the vHost as you appear to be doing?

Comment: They way my server is set up, the html sits at /var/www/example.com/public_html.  Checking on the 1st part of your comment

Comment: Right now I can't seem to get to trace the rewrites. I placed 'LogLevel alert rewrite:trace8' into the example.com.conf file.  Is that the wrong place?

Comment: I have so many 'confs' files. For each domain, the 000-default one. Where do I place the Rewrite log level? Everywhere I have tried and I can't restart apache because of a syntax error.

Comment: @DanielKaplan "the html sits at /var/www/example.com/public_html" - in that case, it should be `DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html`, not `DocumentRoot /var/www/html` as in your earlier comment. "I placed 'LogLevel alert rewrite:trace8' into the example.com.conf file. Is that the wrong place?" - You need to place the directive in the vHost container that relates to the site you are accessing. Each "domain" (or "site", if you have multiple domains) would often have a single conf file, named according to the canonical domain. `000-default` is just the _default_.

Comment: @DanielKaplan "I can't restart apache because of a syntax error." - what is the error reported in the logs?